# How to fade the edge of a View in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYu9o.jpg)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLyRF.png)

How to fade the edge of a View like the above images in react native?

Comment: @gdbj I wish I can include some code but unfortunately I have zero idea of how to implement it. After some research I know similar effects can be done in web(css) or native environment (swift/java) but I don't think the relevant code is helpful for this question.

Comment: If you are looking for horizontal scroll implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/74373740/9706357

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ScrollView fadeingEdgeLength equivalent for iOS in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370879/scrollview-fadeingedgelength-equivalent-for-ios-in-react-native)

Comment: @JohnMiller: how about this: better to include the image directly, instead of a link.  :). The internet is always evolving, and links tend to break over time, and when that happens, this question will no longer have any meaning.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On iOS, you can use the [`MaskedViewIOS`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/maskedviewios.html) component to create an transparent alpha mask for the fading effect.

For the fading gradient itself, you can either use something like [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) (which is also built into Expo) or a semi-transparent image (black pixels will show content through, transparent pixels will block masked content).

```
<MaskedViewIOS 
  maskElement={
    <LinearGradient colors={['black', 'transparent']} />
  }
>
  <YourContent />
</MaskedViewIOS>
```

Here is an [example on Snack](https://snack.expo.io/rJuantw8z).

Unfortunately, MaskedView is not yet implemented on Android. I'm not aware of a simple way of implementing this, but would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: note that `MaskedViewIOS` has moved to https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view and thus Android support is now also included.

Answer (score 14):

I know this post is old but for anyone looking at this now, you can set a fadingEdgeLength on your ScrollView like this to achieve that effect. Note that it only works for Android though. For example:

```
<ScrollView fadingEdgeLength={100}>
  ... scroll view content ...
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Note that this also works with a `FlatList` and `VirtualizedList`, as they inherit the `ScrollView` props.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your view in something like

```
<BackgroundContainer>
  <LinearGradient>
    <UserList>
  </LinearGradient>
</BackgroundContainer>
```

from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

then use alpha channels (rgba()) to get the transparency effect you're looking for.

Comment: This won't work for the first use case, as the gradient applies only to the background, and doesn't mask the child components. AFAIK there isn't an easy way to do this with React Native currently.

Comment: @jevakallio You can just use absolute positioning with the gradient component.

Comment: @Palisand check the first example image with the transparent fade -- that won't work. For solid color, you can overlay it to fake the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small example using [`@react-native-community/masked-view`](https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view) and [`react-native-linear-gradient`](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient)

Think it will help for someone :)

```
import React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';
import MaskedView from '@react-native-community/masked-view';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={{ uri: 'https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1567831.jpg' }}
      >
        <MaskedView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          maskElement={<LinearGradient style={{ flex: 1 }} colors={['white', 'transparent']} />}
        >
          <ScrollView>
            {
              Array(100).fill(null).map((x, i) => <Text key={i}>{i}</Text>)
            }
          </ScrollView>
        </MaskedView>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: New package name is: @react-native-masked-view/masked-view

Answer (score 0):

You can use: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-masked-view.

It supports both Android and iOS.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MaskedView from '@react-native-community/masked-view';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MaskedView
        style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: '100%' }}
        maskElement={
          <View
            style={{
              // Transparent background because mask is based off alpha channel.
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 60,
                color: 'black',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
              }}
            >
              Basic Mask
            </Text>
          </View>
        }
      >
        {/* Shows behind the mask, you can put anything here, such as an image */}
        <View style={{ flex: 1, height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#324376' }} />
        <View style={{ flex: 1, height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#F5DD90' }} />
        <View style={{ flex: 1, height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#F76C5E' }} />
        <View style={{ flex: 1, height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#e1e1e1' }} />
      </MaskedView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This example does not make it clear how to achieve the effect op is asking for.