# Is it possible to edit react-native Text component's noOfLines ellipsis style?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

Currently `noOfLines` is giving ellipsis in `'...'` style .But I want to modify the `...` style into **faded shadow** at the end . is It possible to override the  `noOfLines` style of `<Text>` component or any alternative way to do it.

**current design :**

```
<Text numberOfLines={1}>long long Verification Substance long text<Text>
```

[image]

**Expected design :** *(instead of ellipsis, I need just faded shadow at the end applied on the Text component)*

[image]

Comment: You might want to check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650156/how-to-fade-the-edge-of-a-view-in-react-native

Comment: Also check this link: https://benestudio.co/how-to-indicate-content-overflow-with-react-scrollfade/