# ScrollView fadeingEdgeLength equivalent for iOS in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, typescript, react-native, scrollview

fadingEdgeLength prop of ScrollView is available only for android. Is there any equivalent for this for iOS or maybe any other way we could do this.

Docs:
`https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#fadingedgelength-android`

PS: I am trying to achieve this UI.
[image: Youtube badges]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this to work with MaskedView and LinearGradient.

https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient
https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view

```
      <MaskedView
        style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: '100%' }}
        maskElement={
          <LinearGradient
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              height: '100%',
            }}
            colors={['transparent', 'white', 'white', 'transparent']}
            locations={[0, 0.1, 0.9, 1]}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
          />
        }>
           ...<ScrollView horizontally ... />
     </MaskedView>
```