# react native item's opacity on the bottom of FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

[image]

i want to put fade out effect on the bottom edge of the flatlist like that design prototype above.

But I have no idea what should i do.

i tried some instructions like this.
`https://dev.to/mazahir26/how-to-create-animated-flatlist-in-react-native-564e`

But most of the examples are based on the scroll offset.

i think it has nothing to do with Animated.FlatList, but i need to deal with Animated.View inside of ListItem component.
Could anybody help me?

here is the code.
Home.tsx

```
...

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[{flex: 1, backgroundColor: theme.color.black}]}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          scrollEnabled={true}
          data={alarmList}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <ListItem
              active={true}
              date={new Date()}
              message={'hello'}
              soundName={'marimba'}
              setUpdated={setUpdated}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

ListItem.tsx

```
export default function ListItem(props: listItemProps) {
  const {active, soundName, date, message, setUpdated} = props;

  const renderRightActions = (
    progress: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation<any>,
    dragAnimatedValue: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation<any>,
  ) => {
    const scale = dragAnimatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [-50, 0],
      outputRange: [0, 5],
    });
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.rightActionView, {transform: [{translateX: scale}]}]}>
        <Pressable
          style={({pressed}) => [{opacity: pressed ? 0.2 : 1}]}>
          <Icon name="Trash" color={theme.color.text_primary} size={30} />
        </Pressable>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Swipeable
      childrenContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: theme.color.black}}
      renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
      <Animated.View style={[viewStyle(active).itemView, {
        transform: // ...?
      }]}>
      ...
      </Animated.View>
    </Swipeable>
  );
}
```

Comment: What you want to do is, when the toggle is off, it should reduce the opacity of the item?

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara No, I've already done that. I want to do that fade effect on the edge of the flatlist. Sorry i think i need to edit the post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fade the edge of a View in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650156/how-to-fade-the-edge-of-a-view-in-react-native)

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara Do you know any good example that deals with the Animated component? instead of just fading out mask layer

Comment: I doubt what you want is possible with Animated API.

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara Solved it. Thanks for your advice! :)

Comment: How do you solve this?